# Why Ionic doesn't apply in-line css to dynamically newly added Ion slide?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying implement ionic slide box with dynamic ion slide. I am using `ng-repeat` (don't know if collection-repeat should be used here or not) to multiply the `<ion-slide>` and handling the addition of new slide on on-slide-changed event like below:

```
var i = 0;
$scope.slideHasChanged = function($index) {
    if($index == $scope.data.news.length - 1) {
        $scope.data.news.push({title:'Test '+(++i)});
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
    }
}
```

Its working fine, but its pushing new slide below the currently focused slide and its visible, which looks weird.

Also, when I removed every parent ionic element like `<ion-view>` and `<ion-content>` from the view and kept only `<ion-slide-box>` in entire page, its working fine without pushing new slide below, which I do not want since I have other logic behinds `<ion-view>` and `<ion-content>` ? So my question is **how to make slide box working properly under view or content tag ?**

below is my non-working code sample:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
   <ion-content class="row-center col-center">      
     <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" show-pager="false">
      <ion-slide ng-repeat="news in data.news">
            <h1>{{news.title}}</h1>
            <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg" />
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>        
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

(Please note, slide box is working properly after I remove ion view and content from the page)

**UPDATE**
http://codepen.io/agupta1989/pen/MwGbOW?editors=101

After few trial and analysis in Chrome, I found on `on-slide-change` event, in controller, when I am adding new slide dynamically, Ionic failed to apply in-line css to newly added `<ion-slide>`. Please have look below:

```
<div class="slider-slides" ng-transclude="" style="width: 1080px;"> 
    <!-- ngRepeat: news in data.newsCards -->
<ion-slide ng-repeat="news in data.newsCards" class="slider-slide" data-index="0" style="width: 360px; left: 0px; transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transform: translate(-360px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
    <!-- Content ommitted -->
</ion-slide><!-- end ngRepeat: news in data.newsCards -->
<ion-slide ng-repeat="news in data.newsCards" class="slider-slide" data-index="1" style="width: 360px; left: -360px; transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transform: translate(-360px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
    <!-- Content ommitted -->
</ion-slide><!-- end ngRepeat: news in data.newsCards -->
<ion-slide ng-repeat="news in data.newsCards" class="slider-slide" data-index="2" style="width: 360px; left: -720px; transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
    <!-- Content ommitted -->
</ion-slide><!-- end ngRepeat: news in data.newsCards -->
<ion-slide ng-repeat="news in data.newsCards" class="slider-slide">
    <!-- Content ommitted -->
</ion-slide>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: news in data.newsCards -->
```

Look at the last `<ion-slide>` which doesn't have the in line css. is it a bug or am I doing it in wrong way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I end up with [Swiper](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper) by Idangerous. It have very nice and rich set of API's, methods and events. Here is a [link](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VhNRVCtfK1s). Yes, I had to use [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service from angular to compile those additional slides or html which needs to push dynamically while user swipe. Along with added dynamic slides, I managed to write little algorithm to clean up existing slides using `removeSlides([0,1,2])` and add new slides using `appendSlides()` and `prependSlides()` vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example that should help, you can change max slides or use a collection repeat (so you dont crash to app due to memory issues).
EDIT: This is now working code with no wrapping

HTML:

```
<title>Tabs Example</title>

<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
      <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
      <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>

<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
 <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <ion-slide-box delegate-handle="news-cards" 
        on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" show-pager="false" > 
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="news in data.newsCards">
          <h1>{{news.title}}</h1>
          <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg" style="width:90%;"/> 
        </ion-slide> 
      </ion-slide-box>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Facts">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
      <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
      <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
      <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
      <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
      <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
      <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
      <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
      <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
      <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="About">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
      <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
      <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Contact">
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
          @IonicFramework
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          @DriftyTeam
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 .slider {
  height: 100%;
}
.slider-slide {
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;

  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
}

.slider-pager-page i{
}
```

JS:

```
  angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
  $scope.data = {
            newsCards: []
    }
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(event,state) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.data.newsCards = [{title:'abc'},{title:'xyz'},{title:'pqr'},{title: '123', title: '1234', title:'hello'}];
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('news-cards').update();
    });

    var i = 0;
    $scope.slideHasChanged = function($index) {
        if($index == $scope.data.newsCards.length-1 && $index < 6) {
            $scope.data.newsCards.push({title:'Dummy'+(++i)});
      console.log($scope.data.newsCards);
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('news-cards').update();
        }
        else if($index == 6) {
      alert($index);
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide($index-1);
        }
    }
});
```

Working Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJVNKz

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have already seen this example. Thing is I want to load next slide when slide change, (by calling some API and I want to keep some data in memory e.g 5 slides), apart from this, my issues is something different. its like loading new slide is going beyond the view and wraping  down the current active slide. see image attached

Comment: fixed it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJVNKz I will also change my code in the answer to reflect the fix

Comment: Thank you Jess, but the solution seems to be incomplete. If you could have a look from different view. e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOGpRj/left/ try increase / decrease the frame size, an image is showing just before the last slide.

Comment: hmmm i am very perplexed, i don't know why it breaks it when you use on slide change vs some other method. Maybe it has something to do with the watch and apply cycles and where on slide change falls into those. I am going to have too look at it some more.

Comment: hmm I understand.. :( not able to point out the exact cause or solution for this.. its eating my brain !